# Rails: finding a record in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I have a Url class with the following attributes in the database:

```
def self.up
    create_table :urls do |t|
      t.string :url, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

I would like to find if there is already a record of that URL in the database, but although a request looks like `"url"=>{"url"=>"y"}` and I do a `existing_url = Url.find(params[:url])`, I cannot retrieve it, as I get a `Unknown key(s): url` error.

How can I find whether a certain URL is already in the DB?

Cheers!
M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
existing_url = Url.find(params[:url][:url])
```

which is actually should look like this, I believe:

```
existing_url = Url.find_by_url(params[:url][:url])
```

or in Rails 3 syntax

```
existing_url = Url.where(:url => params[:url][:url])
```

Answer (score 0):

`Url.find_by_url(params[:url])` or `Url.where(:url => params[:url])`